# Laravels flash session stores data twice

Tags: laravel

this ones a head ache! From my understanding of laravel's flash method for sessions, once it has been set then called, it will be destroyed...

```
Session::flash( 'key', $data );
```

somewhere down the line

```
{{ Session::get( 'key' ) }}
```

I am using this for form validation. Now when the form does not validate, the application displayed the error, if I amend the form and post again, the database updates, the details are displayed correctly, but the error appears again! This is the same for if I post the form that doesn't validate, it displays the error, but if I then click the navigation link for the same page, it displays again!

Anyone come across this?

regards

Luke

Comment: How have you confirmed that the flash data is the problem?  Can you post your validation code?

Comment: I have same issue also !!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had this problem once when I did a `return view()` / `return View::Make` when it should be a `return redirect()->route()` in my Controller@update method.

Answer (score 5):

Since Laravel 5.1, you can use the [now()](https://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Session/Store.html#method_now) method which will only affect the current request :

```
Session::now('key', 'message');
```

or

```
session()->now('key', 'message');
```

Comment: @alvarofvr Not a question but an answer here ;)

Comment: Ahahahah sorry =)

Answer (score 3):

Out of the laravel docs:

> The flash method stores an item in the session that will expire **after the next request**. It's useful for storing temporary data like status or error messages.

This means, it's available at the current and also the next request. It does not get flushed automatically if you access it. To do so, use `Session::flush('key');`.

Answer (score 2):

Session Flash preserves the session data for 2 requests because it was meant to be used during redirection.

However, I've came across a use case where I do want to use flash for just 1 request in the next view and found an easy way to do it, which is to pull from the session rather than get it. The `Session::pull()` gets the session data and removes from the session.

```
@if (Session::has('message'))
   <div class="alert alert-message">{{Session::pull('message'}}</div>
@endif
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

It's probably some other issue with your code, if you could share your code it would help us get a better insight into this issue.

You can use the below code snippet to Flash Error messages to your laravel blade template.

```
@if (Session::has('message'))

    <div class="alert alert-success">{{Session::get('message')}}</div>

@endif
```

Answer (score 0):

I once had similar issue because i used `Session::reflash()` in my controller.

Ensure you don't have `Session::reflash()` somewhere in your controller or anywhere in your application, as it flashes whole session... use example: `Session::keep(array('username', 'email'));` to reflashing only A Subset Of Flash Data

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to flash a message once when you are creating a view (and not redirecting) is:

```
Session::flash($key, $value);
Session::push('flash.old', $key);
```

Refer [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24579580/laravel-session-flash-persists-for-2-requests/31743850#31743850)

Answer (score 0):

The `flash` method is meant for storing the data for the next request. Ideally after flashing the data to the session you should be redirecting to a new route. (This is what the accepted answer suggests.)

But if you are not redirecting you can call the `forget` method after displaying the session in your blade template:

```
{{ session()->flash('key') }}

@php
    session()->forget('flash-info');
@endphp
```

Comment: You do know I asked this question 5 years ago dont you?

Comment: yes, but it is not just OP who benefits from the answers. People refer to these questions and they expect the answers working in the new version of the tools. Yesterday this question came up for me in the Google search. There were other similar questions, but I chose to answer here because they had mush less views.