# Laravel Session Flash persists for 2 requests

Tags: php, session, laravel, laravel-4

Recently I have changed to Laravel from Codeigniter, everything was going fine except I encountered a problem with `Session::flash`.

when I create new user I get success message but It will persist for 2 requests, even I didn't pass the validator:
[image]

my code in `UsersController`:

```
function getCreateUser(){
    $config = array(
        'pageName' => 'createUser',
        'pageTitle' => 'Create User',
        'formUrl'   => action('UsersController@postCreateUser'),
        'modelFields'   => array(
            array('db_name' => 'employee_id', 'text' => 'Employee Id', 'mandatory' => TRUE),
            array('db_name' => 'full_name', 'text' => 'Full Name', 'mandatory' => TRUE),
            array('db_name' => 'email', 'text' => 'Email', 'mandatory' => FALSE),
            array('db_name' => 'password', 'text' => 'Password','value' => '12345', 'mandatory' => TRUE)
            ),
        'submit_text' => 'Create'
        );
    return View::make('layouts.form', $config);
}

function postCreateUser(){
    $config = array(
        'pageName' => 'createUser',
        'pageTitle' => 'Create User',
        'formUrl'   => action('UsersController@postCreateUser'),
        'modelFields'   => array(
            array('db_name' => 'employee_id', 'text' => 'Employee Id', 'mandatory' => TRUE),
            array('db_name' => 'full_name', 'text' => 'Full Name', 'mandatory' => TRUE),
            array('db_name' => 'email', 'text' => 'Email', 'mandatory' => FALSE),
            array('db_name' => 'password', 'text' => 'Password','value' => '12345', 'mandatory' => TRUE)
            ),
        'submit_text' => 'Create'
        );
    $validator = User::validate(Input::all());
    if($validator->passes()){
        $user = new User(Input::all());
        $user->password = Hash::make(Input::get('password'));
        $user->Company_id = '1';
        $user->save();

        Session::flash('message', 'User Created Successfully!'); 
        Session::flash('alert-class', 'alert-success');
        return View::make('layouts.form', $config);
    } 

    return View::make('layouts.form', $config)->withErrors($validator->messages());
}
```

in `form.blade`:

```
@if ( $errors->count() > 0 )
<div class="alert alert-danger">
    <p>The following errors have occurred:</p>

    <ul>
        @foreach( $errors->all() as $message )
        <li>{{ $message }}</li>
        @endforeach
    </ul>
</div>
@endif
```

in `master.blade`:

```
@if(Session::has('message'))
<p class="alert {{ Session::get('alert-class', 'alert-info') }} alert-dismissable"> {{ Session::get('message') }}</p>
@endif
```

Maybe I'm not alone with this issue, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14517809/laravels-flash-session-stores-data-twice/14520060#14520060) is another unanswered question.

### Update

For anyone in future facing this problem: 
**Never flash session data without redirecting.**

My code now looks like this:

```
function postCreateUser(){
    $validator = User::validate(Input::all());
    if($validator->passes()){
        $user = new User(Input::all());
        $user->password = Hash::make(Input::get('password'));
        $user->Company_id = '1';
        $user->save();

        Session::flash('message', 'User Created Successfully!'); 
        Session::flash('alert-class', 'alert-success');
    } else {
        Session::flash('message', Helpers::formatErrors($validator->messages()->all()));
        Session::flash('alert-class', 'alert-danger');
    }

    return Redirect::action('UsersController@getCreateUser');
}
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You are Flashing session data and creating a view instead of redirecting, meaning the message will Flash for this request and for the next one, showing twice.

If you want to show the message on the current request without redirecting, I would suggest providing the errors to your `View::make` instead of trying to Flash the messages. If you MUST Flash the message on the current request, then you will need to `Session::forget('key')` or `Session::flush()` after your view.

Comment: Thanks for your clarification, I have solved the problem after your answer.

Comment: I could not get flash message. Let me know what's an exact issue.

Comment: @Drew: Session::flush('key') is not a valid function call, flush() does not take any argument, instead it deletes all session data, can you please update your answer? Session::forget('key') can be used to delete any session data, I suggest :)

Answer (score 24):

The following seems to be available from version 5.1 onward. It used to be undocumented, now it is: see [Laravel's session documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/session#flash-data).

```
session()->now()
```

This is the same as `flash`, except it won't persist to the next request.

Answer (score 6):

As @Drew  said earlier

> You are Flashing session data and creating a view instead of
>   redirecting, meaning the message will Flash for this request and for
>   the next one, showing twice.

An easy way to flash a message once when you are creating a view is:

```
Session::flash($key, $value);
Session::push('flash.old', $key);
```

Happy coding!

Comment: For anyone else sort of confused by this like I was, if you are flashing like this: `Flash::warning('warning text');` then what you want to follow up with is `Session::push('flash.old', 'flash_notification.message');` and `Session::push('flash.old', 'flash_notification.level');`. This will make it only display on the first page load. You can `dd($request->session());` to see how the session stores these values if you want.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem, but I couldn't use Return::redirct, as I was using Ajax to to post to and from a  within a set of Tabs.

Therefore, I was calling

```
Input::flashExcept('_token');
```

only if the validation failed and returning a view with the old input. Assuming validation passed and I wanted to run some functions and create a new view based on new data, I would call:

```
Session::forget('_old_input');
```

I would put this before my final `View::make`

Hope this helps (or makes sense)...

Answer (score 1):

**create:**

```
$request->session()->flash('status', 'Task was successful!');
```

**delete:**

```
$request->session()->forget('status');
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the scope of your Api's both session put and session get Api's have to be in same scope(i e web.php or api.php).

Answer (score -1):

A good method to repopulate form with old data:

Controller:

```
View::make( 'view.name' )->withOldFormData( Input::all() );
```

View:

```
{{ Form::model( $old_form_data ) }}
```

Comment: How does this answer apply to the question?

Comment: This is an alternate method to solve the problem. Instead of redirecting to a new route, he can populate form with this safe method !